# How to calculate spherical angles for Bloch vector

Tags: qiskit, mathematics, textbook-and-exercises

I am doing the 5th exercise on https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-states/representing-qubit-states.html#Quick-Exercise (all the way at the bottom).

Which states find the angle for the vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}i\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.
I find that $$\cos\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad e^{i\phi} \sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right) =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}.$$

I don't know how to find the angles. Or do I just leave it in the form of cosine and sine inverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is find a parametrisation of the state in the form
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c} \cos\frac{\theta}{2} \\ \sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi} \end{array}\right)
$$
However, you'll notice that the first element *is real*, while it isn't in your state, so they cannot be matched. Instead, what is actually going on where is that you require *equivalence up to a global phase*. Hence, you should write your state as
$$
i\left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}} \end{array}\right).
$$
So, now you can try to match up
$$
\left(\begin{array}{c} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{-i}{\sqrt{2}} \end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} \cos\frac{\theta}{2} \\ \sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\phi} \end{array}\right).
$$
From this, you'll see that $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and hence $\theta=\pi/2$. It then follows that $e^{i\phi}=-i$ and hence $\phi=3\pi/2$.

Answer (score 2):

The complex number $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ shows up in a lot situations. It's a primitive eighth root of unity so it equals $e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}$. Also note that $i$ is a primitive fourth root of unity, so it equals $e^{i \frac{\pi}{2}}$.  So in this case $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\phi = \frac{3 \pi}{2}$, which gives this state after pulling out a global phase of $i$.  Global phases do not impact outcome probabilities, so states are considered equivalent if they are equal up to a global phase.

More generally if you suspect an angle is a rational multiple of $\pi$, but you aren't sure of the value, you can just enter, for example, `acos(1/2^.5)/pi`, or equivalently `log(1/2^.5+i/2^.5)/pi`, into your favorite math software, which in this case will spit out $0.25$ for the first and $0.25i$ for the second.